# Custom theme dependencies

Tags: 9

I have a problem with a custom theme I created on a Drupal 9 test site.

- Drupal version: 9.3.13
- Web server Apache 2.4.41 (XAMP win64)
- PHP version 8.0.11
- Database version 10.4.8-MariaDB

custom theme professional.info.yml:

```
name: Professional
type: theme
description: Drupal 9 version of Professional theme
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
base theme: false
version: 1.0.0
libraries:
  - professional/global-styling
  - professional/global-scripts
regions:
  sidebar_first: 'First Sidebar'
  sidebar_second: 'Second Sidebar'
  header: 'Header'
  front_welcome: 'Front Welcome'
  content: 'Content'
  content_top: 'Content Top'
  help: 'Help'
  footer: 'Footer'
  footer_first: 'First Bottom'
  footer_second: 'Second Bottom'
  footer_third: 'Third Bottom'
features:
  logo: true
  site_name: true
  site_slogan: true
  node_user_picture: true
  comment_user_picture: true
  comment_user_verification: true
  favicon: true
  main_menu: true
  secondary_menu: false
```

custom theme professional.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}  
global-scripts:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
    js/jquery.flexslider-min.js: {}
    js/slide.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/drupal.dialog.ajax
```

I saved all the files of the new theme respecting the convention:

```
/site-root
 - themes
   - professional
     - css
     - js
     - templates
       - system
```

The problem is that the dependencies, including core/drupal, are not applied at all, and the three JavaScript files in the `global-scripts` directive are not included in the site pages, even though both Drupal core CSS files as well as style.css from `professional:global-styling` have been included.

I saw that on the chrome browser development tools console when I tried for example to show a basic page
node in a modal popup using a Drupal.org example:

```
<ol>
    <li><a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/xampp/drupal9test/node/9">Basic page displayed in modal dialog. </a></li>
    <li><a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}" data-dialog-type="dialog" href="/xampp/drupal9test/node/9">Basic page displayed in non modal dialog. </a></li>
    <li><a class="edit-button use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}" data-dialog-renderer="off_canvas" data-dialog-type="dialog" href="/xampp/drupal9test/node/9">Basic page displayed in a nice off canvas dialog. </a></li>
</ol>
```

The node is shown as a conventional page, no modal popup is open. So neither core JavaScript nor AJAX is applied if I use my custom theme; when I switch to the Bartik theme, everything is working, modals too.
I tried adding Drupal core and AJAX libraries directly in `professional_preprocess_page(&$variables)` in the professional.theme file with the line:

```php
$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal';
$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'professional/global-scripts';
```

I even tried to add libraries with Twig directly in the html.html.twig template with `{{ attach_library('core/drupal') }}`, but none of these changes did have any effect.

Of course, every time I changed some settings I also cleared the site cache.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: I can't tell you what you're doing wrong, but I'm betting it's a template issue, and you're missing something required. Have you implemented `html.html.twig`? Maybe you have something strange.

Comment: Does your theme overwrite the `html.html.twig` template? You *must* have all three `<css-placeholder>` and `<js-placeholder>`s in there, see https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.5.x/core/themes/stable9/templates/layout/html.html.twig#L31

Comment: Yes, since Bartik works and yours does not, you are missing something fundamental. You have no base theme set, so something is missing as other commenters noted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I managed to solve the problem, but I had to add the custom js files in the <head> section of html.html.twig and the     <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}"> right before the </body> tag, but the line     <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}"> in the <head> section was already there, and it was useless... I thought that indicating custom libraries and dependencies in libraries.yml file was enough to make it work.

Comment: It should work. Re-iterating that there must be something else wrong. Are you following Drupal JavaScript API re behaviors and injecting dependencies with an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)? Providing the javascript could help.

Comment: @mradcliffe: I don't know the answer to your question, but if you like I can make the whole custom theme available to everybody (provided that you explain me where and how I can upload it), so if someone feels like debugging and improving it it can be a new choice for all users all around the world, after all I just modified someone else's theme for Drupal 7.